# How to add spaces between buttons in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

> Sorry if this is an easy question, I'm new to programming. I want to make my buttons to not stick to each other (I want space between the buttons). I managed to do it with adding blank labels between them. I don't know if this is efficient. Is there any other way to put spaces between them?

```
button1 = Button(gui, text="1", pady= 15, padx= 20).pack()
label = Label(gui, text=" ", pady= 0.5, padx= 0.5).pack()
button2 = Button(gui, text="2", pady= 15, padx= 20).pack()
label = Label(gui, text=" ", pady= 0.5, padx= 0.5).pack()
button3 = Button(gui, text="3", pady= 15, padx= 20).pack()
label = Label(gui, text=" ", pady= 0.5, padx= 0.5).pack()
button4 = Button(gui, text="4", pady= 15, padx= 20).pack()
label = Label(gui, text=" ", pady= 0.5, padx= 0.5).pack()
button5 = Button(gui, text="5", pady= 15, padx= 20).pack()
label = Label(gui, text=" ", pady= 0.5, padx= 0.5).pack()
button6 = Button(gui, text="6", pady= 15, padx= 20).pack()
```

Comment: All you need to do is read the documentation on the `pack` command, it lists all of the options available to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
button1 = Button(gui, text="1", pady= 15, padx= 20).pack(pady= 15, padx= 20)
button2 = Button(gui, text="2", pady= 15, padx= 20).pack(pady= 15, padx= 20)
button3 = Button(gui, text="3", pady= 15, padx= 20).pack(pady= 15, padx= 20)
button4 = Button(gui, text="4", pady= 15, padx= 20).pack(pady= 15, padx= 20)
button5 = Button(gui, text="5", pady= 15, padx= 20).pack(pady= 15, padx= 20)
button6 = Button(gui, text="6", pady= 15, padx= 20).pack(pady= 15, padx= 20)
```

padx and pady inside Button function makes buttons larger in size. While inside pack adds the space between.